# ROS on 15.10 (is there a way to install packages for 14.04?)

Tags: 14.04, wireless, drivers, 15.10

I'm running 15.10. I'm trying to install ROS but there is no official support for anything above 14.04. According to this: http://answers.ros.org/question/220064/ros-on-ubuntu-wily/
There will not be support for 15.10 until next summer but installing from source is an option.

I tried to compile from source following these instructions: http://wiki.ros.org/indigo/Installation/Source but at step 2 I get a slew of dependency errors and nothing works. I get about 2 pages worth of the following:

```
rosdep install --from-paths src --ignore-src --rosdistro indigo -y
ERROR: the following packages/stacks could not have their rosdep keys resolved
to system dependencies:
rosconsole: No definition of [boost] for OS version [wily]
camera_info_manager: No definition of [boost] for OS version [wily]
pcl_conversions: No definition of [libpcl-all-dev] for OS version [wily]
image_view: No definition of [libopencv-dev] for OS version [wily]
class_loader: No definition of [libconsole-bridge-dev] for OS version [wily]
urdf: No definition of [liburdfdom-headers-dev] for OS version [wily]
rosgraph: No definition of [python-mock] for OS version [wily]
...
```

I've tried wiping 15.10 and installing 14.04 but I can't get 14.04 to recognize my wifi card; I've got a new computer (inspiron 13 7000, wifi card: Intel® Dual Band Wireless-AC 3165 + Bluetooth 4.0) and apparently 14.04 doesn't have drivers for it. I don't have an Ethernet port so theres no way for a wired connection and I wasn't able to figure out a workaround so I reverted to 15.10.

Does anyone have any ideas on this? Is there a way to install packages meant for older versions? Or is there a way to get the wifi drivers from 15.10 on 14.04? I'm not really sure whats possible but I really hope theres a solution!

Thank you!

In case its relevant,    `lspci` gives

```
00:00.0 Host bridge: Intel Corporation Sky Lake Host Bridge/DRAM Registers (rev 08)
00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation Sky Lake Integrated Graphics (rev 07)
00:04.0 Signal processing controller: Intel Corporation Device 1903 (rev 08)
00:14.0 USB controller: Intel Corporation Device 9d2f (rev 21)
00:15.0 Signal processing controller: Intel Corporation Device 9d60 (rev 21)
00:15.1 Signal processing controller: Intel Corporation Device 9d61 (rev 21)
00:16.0 Communication controller: Intel Corporation Device 9d3a (rev 21)
00:17.0 SATA controller: Intel Corporation Device 9d03 (rev 21)
00:1c.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation Device 9d14 (rev f1)
00:1f.0 ISA bridge: Intel Corporation Device 9d48 (rev 21)
00:1f.2 Memory controller: Intel Corporation Device 9d21 (rev 21)
00:1f.3 Audio device: Intel Corporation Device 9d70 (rev 21)
00:1f.4 SMBus: Intel Corporation Device 9d23 (rev 21)
01:00.0 Network controller: Intel Corporation Wireless 3165 (rev 79)
```

Comment: You might try making another partition for 14.04 (rather than wiping out 15.10) and getting a usb wifi for when you are are in 14.04.

Comment: I don't really care if I'm running 15 or 14, I'd go for 14 if only I could get the wifi driver somehow. I'll see if I can find someone to lend me a usb wifi stick but I'm not hopefully. Thanks though!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes it is possible to install Ros in Ubuntu 15.10. Indigo is not officially supported on Ubuntu Wily. Unresolvable dependencies are exactly the kind of issue you run into then. You could attempt to install a full stack from-source using a chroot. [How to install ros-indigo from sources in a chroot?](http://userk.co.uk/ubuntu-15.10-install-ros-indigo-sources-chroot/)

Hope it helps.